# jQuery scroll function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, function, scroll, jquery-animate, jquery-click-event

I have a scroll function on my page that loads when the url is .../originalmusic.html#prices, when '#prices' is added it flicks down to the Prices section with id="prices". So it works quite alright, but I want it to animate scrolling down and I don't know why it doesn't do that. I have tried changing the delay time but that doesn't work either.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#prices').click(function(){

      $("html, body").delay(1000).animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() });

   }); 

});
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try removing body tag like this.. $("html").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() });

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't do the the trick :/